# Inverse black and white / monochrome bitmapdata in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm wondering if there are any nice ways of inversing a black and white / monochrome bitmapdata in AS3 which don't involve going through and setting each pixel by pixel?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look up `bitmapData.colorTransform()` [[docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#colorTransform%28%29)] and the `ColorTransform` class [[docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/ColorTransform.html)]

You'll probably want to apply something like:

```
var bd:BitmapData;
var invertTransform:ColorTransform = new ColorTransform(-1,-1,-1,1,255,255,255,0)
db.colorTransform(db.rect, invertTransform)
```

Which will multiply each pixel by -1 and then add 255. so 255 will become 0 and 0 will become 255.

Comment: missing monochrome

Comment: @payamsbr if you want to know how to *make an image monochrome* then you should ask that in a different question.

Comment: @32bitkid if find it myself with threshold,  thank you, but this was asked in this question and might be answered here, i'll post my own answer here

Answer (score 8):

There's also another solution. Every display object has a **blendMode** property and has the capability to alter the color of the background objects according to that blend mode. All you have to do is to cover the bitmap object with another display object and set its blend mode. It works pretty similar to masks but applies to color instead of shape.

```
colorCoverObject.blendMode = BlendMode.INVERT;
```

The `colorCoverObject` should be a transparent object.

Answer (score 1):

For ActionScript 2.0:

```
colorCoverObject.blendMode="invert";
```

The movie clips behind the colorCoverObject displayin inverted color.

Answer (score 0):

for **monochrome** effect i just created a tutorial below

the preview of monochrome effect:

[image]

---

### required:

1. understanding Bitmap and Bitmap data

---

**what is threshold**

> This adjustment takes all the pixels in an image
>   and…pushes them to either pure white or pure black

**what we have to do**

> here is a **[Live Demo](http://www.fastswf.com/inDKZD8)** of this example with some additional
>   changes like using a UI to changing threshold level in runtime.
>
> [image]

**threshold in action script 3**
<sub>[from as3 official documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#threshold())</sub>

> Tests pixel values in an image against a specified threshold and sets
>   pixels that pass the test to new color values. Using the threshold()
>   method, you can isolate and replace color ranges in an image and
>   perform other logical operations on image pixels.
>
> **The threshold() method's test logic is as follows:**
>
> 1. If ((pixelValue & mask) operation (threshold & mask)), then set the
>      pixel to color;
> 2. Otherwise, if copySource == true, then set the pixel to
>      corresponding pixel value from sourceBitmap.

i just commented the following code with exactly names as quoted description.

```
import flash.display.BitmapData;
import flash.display.Bitmap;
import flash.geom.Rectangle;
import flash.geom.Point;

var bmd:BitmapData = new wildcat(); // instantied a bitmapdata from library a wildcat
var bmp:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bmd); // our display object to previewing bitmapdata on stage
addChild(bmp);
monochrome(bmd); // invoking threshold function

/**
    @param bmd, input bitmapData that should be monochromed
*/
function monochrome(bmd:BitmapData):void {
    var bmd_copy:BitmapData = bmd.clone(); // holding a pure copy of bitmapdata for comparation steps
    // this is our "threshold" in description above, source pixels will be compared with this value
    var level:uint = 0xFFAAAAAA; // #AARRGGBB. in this case i used RGB(170,170,170) with an alpha of 1. its not median but standard
    // A rectangle that defines the area of the source image to use as input.
    var rect:Rectangle = new Rectangle(0,0,bmd.width,bmd.height);
    // The point within the destination image (the current BitmapData instance) that corresponds to the upper-left corner of the source rectangle.
    var dest:Point = new Point();
    // thresholding will be done in two section
    // the last argument is "mask", which exists in both sides of comparation
    // first, modifying pixels which passed comparation and setting them all with "color" white (0xFFFFFFFF)
    bmd.bitmapData.threshold(bmd_copy, rect, dest, ">", level, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    // then, remaining pixels and make them all with "color" black (0xFF000000)
    bmd.bitmapData.threshold(bmd_copy, rect, dest, "<=", level, 0xFF000000, 0xFFFFFFFF);
    // Note: as we have no alpha channel in our default BitmapData (pixelValue), we left it to its full value, a white mask (0xffffffff)
}
```